# How to force select dropdown to expand downwards

Tags: html, css

I'm using a `select` tags to select options from a dropdown list, but due to the number of items, the list goes up, as if its drop-up. I am using Bootstrap.

Checked other codes but not found any result.

```html
 <div class="select-style" style="display: inline-block;">
        <select id="year">
            <option value="hide">-- Year --</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="201">2011</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="201">2011</option>
            <option value="202">2012</option>
            <option value="203">2013</option>
            <option value="204">2014</option>
            <option value="205">2015</option>
            <option value="202">2012</option>
            <option value="203">2013</option>
            <option value="204">2014</option>
            <option value="205">2015</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

---

[image: Screenshot of the homepage]

This option goes upwards when there are more options in the menu. I want it to go in the downward direction.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you provide a screenshot or the full code for your select as well as a screenshot of the expected behavior ?

Comment: This behavior is controlled by the browser and depends on the viewport height above/below the `select` element. You might need to make a custom drop-down.

Comment: I think it's because above the select there is enough space so it can fit in the screen, while below it there isn't.

Comment: how can I change it so that it fits below?

Answer (score 1):

Try `<select id="year" size="5">` you can also ajust the height with css

Comment: not working... the boxes moved in different direction

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS like

CSS:

```
#year {
 width:150px;   
}
```

If you want to change the width of the option you can do this in your css:

```
#year option{
  width:150px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution that will force expanding downwards and you can define the height of the select. Here is the Fiddle (**you need resources**): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kupdhbyr/2/)

```js
$(function(){
    $('select').chosen({width: '100px'});
    
    $('ul.chosen-results').css('min-height', '100px');
    $('ul.chosen-results').css('max-height', '100px');
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value='1'>2010</option>
  <option value='2'>2011</option>
  <option value='1'>2012</option>
  <option value='2'>2013</option>
  <option value='1'>2014</option>
  <option value='2'>2015</option>
  <option value='1'>2016</option>
  <option value='2'>2017</option>
  <option value='1'>2018</option>
  <option value='2'>2019</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

set offset attribute in negative number until it moves downward.
(it worked for me in material tailwind components)

```
<select id="year" offset={-50}>
<option value="hide">-- Year --</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="201">2011</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="201">2011</option>
<option value="202">2012</option>
<option value="203">2013</option>
<option value="204">2014</option>
<option value="205">2015</option>
<option value="202">2012</option>
<option value="203">2013</option>
<option value="204">2014</option>
<option value="205">2015</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `data-dropup-auto="false"`

Example:

```html
<div class="select-style" data-dropup-auto="false" style="display: inline-block;">
    <select id="year">
        <option value="hide">-- Year --</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="201">2011</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="201">2011</option>
        <option value="202">2012</option>
        <option value="203">2013</option>
        <option value="204">2014</option>
        <option value="205">2015</option>
        <option value="202">2012</option>
        <option value="203">2013</option>
        <option value="204">2014</option>
        <option value="205">2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Try running the snippet with the page scrolled such that the selector is in the bottom half of the page. It still goes up. OP has not specified that they are using Bootstrap.

Comment: @RoshanYadav Are you using Bootstrap? if so, try using `data-flip="false"`, if that still doesn't work, you'll have to disable the default behaviour of your browser that flips your dropdown menu.

Comment: Still the same, yes I am using bootstrap